# Modifying an item in List

Tags: c#, linq, list, c#-4.0

I have the below class structure:

```
List<Parent> ParentList = new List<Parent>();
```

```
class Parent
{
    string ParentName { get; set; }
    List<Child> ChildList = new List<Child>();
}

class Child
{
    string ParentName { get; set; }
    string ChildName { get; set; }
    string someValue { get; set; }
}
```

In the above scenario, I have an object of type `Child` lets keep ChildObject, and a `ParentList` that is populated with data. I would like to modify the `someValue` property present in the `ParentList` to the value that I have in the child object.

I tried this:

```
ParentList.Where(p => p.ParentName == ChildObject.ParentName)
    .Select(c => c.ChildList
        .Where(ch => ch.ChildName == ChildObject.ChildName)
        .Select(s => s.someValue = ChildObject.someValue));
```

but my property value is not set. How this can be written?

Comment: You should not be modifying the original data with Linq queries.

Comment: Any particular reason for this. Is it best to use linq only for retreiveal?

Comment: Linq is for functional programming and should not cause side effects. See ["foreach" vs "ForEach"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx)

Comment: I don't understand why you have ChildList inside the Parent class? Child contains ParentName so it's pointless to have a list that has no association in there, or am i missing something?

Comment: @jzm, `ParentName` might not be a unique identifier. My question is, why store the `ParentName` at all? Either you have to go through a Parent to get to the child, or store the Parent object within the Child for reference.

Comment: Oh, and make sure you make those properties `public`, or else nothing can access them outside the classes.

Comment: @gunr2171 It is if you look at his sample code. ParentList.ParentName == ChildObject.ParentName. He's basically keeping a full list of Childs inside the Parent object for no reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to update all children of a parent you can use the `List.ForEach()` method.

```
// assumes childObject is your instance of a child you have from elsewhere
parentList
    // assuming parent name is unique
    .First(p => p.ParentName == childObject.ParentName)
    // not sure if child name is unique, allowing multiple
    .ChildList.Where(c => c.ChildName == childObject.ChildName)
    // convert to List<Child> so we can use ForEach()
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(c => c.someValue = childObject.someValue);
```

If there might be multiple parents then you'll want to change to `SelectMany`, update your question as needed.

If you only expect a single child of a single parent, then you don't need to use `Where` and `Select`, just use `First` on both, or `FirstOrDefault` with null checks if you aren't sure if it will be found.

NOTE: `List<T>.ForEach()` is an extension function only found on `List`, while it looks like it fits well with the fluent LINQ syntax it is a very different beast. I would strongly recommend using a `foreach` loop for the modification to avoid confusion. See this link on ["foreach" vs "ForEach"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx) for more detail (credit to @ScottChamberlain for the link).

Comment: Thank you :). It worked for my scenario with slight modifications.

Answer (score 0):

```
var filteredParents =  ParentList.Where(p => p.ParentName == ChildObject.ParentName);
var childItems = filteredParents.ChildList.Where(c=>c.ChildName == ChildObject.ChildName);
childItems.foreach((child)=>{
         child.someValue = ChildObject.someValue;
})
```

Does this work for you? Or do you want to achieve this one statement?